# TypeError: doc.data(...)?.updatedAt?.toMillis is not a function (NextJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm getting this error message when I read the firestore documents using the useCollection hook.

```
TypeError: doc.data(...)?.updatedAt?.toMillis is not a function
```

my useCollection Hook:

```
export const useCollection = (c, q) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    let ref = collection(db, c)

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
      const results = []
      console.log(snapshot.docs.length)
      snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (doc) => {
          results.push({
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
            createdAt: doc.data()?.createdAt.toMillis() || 0,
            updatedAt: doc.data()?.updatedAt?.toMillis() || 0,
          })
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          setError("could not fetch the data")
        }
      )
      // update state
      setDocuments(results)
      setIsLoading(false)
      setError(null)
    })

    // unsubscribe to the previous listener before running the side effect again
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [openTab])

  return { documents, error, isLoading }
}
```

Intially, when I first save the document to firestore, I set the value of `updatedAt` to `0`. At time of reading, it's throughing the error message.

Anyone, please help me with this!

Comment: What data types are you saving your `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties? If they're not [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp) types, they won't have those functions

Comment: I wasn't using the Timestamp for updatedAt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving your documents, you will need to ensure you use [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp) types in order to support the `toMillis()` and other functions.

```js
import { addDoc, collection, updateDoc, Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

// create
addDoc(collectionRef, {
  ...someData,
  createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
  updatedAt: Timestamp.now(),
});

// update
updateDoc(docRef, {
  ...someData,
  updatedAt: Timestamp.now(),
});
```